# JQuery set interval and click function dilemma

Tags: jquery, timeout, jquery-selectors, intervals

The following script triggers changes an image every 5000ms or on click.

It users .next() to work out the next thumbnail to click when automatically timing out. The problem is that when the user clicks on a thumbnail the automatic function correctly kicks in after 5000ms, but the next() is not updated based on the users click and the image displayed is not the next image but what would have been the next one if the user had not clicked.

```
var slideShowTO;
     $('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img').click(function(){
         $('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img').removeClass('active')
         $(this).addClass('active');
         var img = '#P' + $(this).attr('id');

         $('#coursepanel .gallery .feature img').removeClass('focus');
         $(img).addClass('focus');
          window.clearInterval(slideShowTO);
            slideShowTO = window.setInterval(function(){

        if($(this).attr('id') == $('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:last').attr('id'))
        {
            $('#coursepanel .thumbstrip img:first').click();
        }
        else {
        $(this).next().click();
        }
    },5000);
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

NB#  I have asked this question before but for some reason the answer from before is not working with a very similar script we have now.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear I had left another script on too that was taking precedence over this one.